# a SELECT or set-returning version of MERGE/UPSERT?

Tags: select, upsert, postgresql-10

I'm learning `MERGE` or `UPSERT` (`UPDATE` + `INSERT`), which according to [wikipeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)), has the form:

```
 MERGE INTO tablename USING table_reference ON (condition)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET column1 = value1 [, column2 = value2 ...]
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (column1 [, column2 ...]) VALUES (value1 [, value2 ...]);
```

, and:

> If the ON field(s) in the Source matches the ON field(s) in the
>   Target, then UPDATE
>
> If the ON field(s) in the Source does not match the ON field(s) in the
>   Target, then INSERT

I was wondering if there is a `SELECT` version of it (without side effects) that returns the would-be result of the updated target table without actually changing the target table?

Using PostgreSQL 9.5's `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT [ conflict_target ] conflict_action` statement (pointed out in wikipedia) as an example. Given a target table `distributors` and an update table `distributors_upd` as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS distributors;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS distributors_upd;

CREATE TABLE distributors (did INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dname VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO distributors
VALUES (5, 'Gizmo Transglobal'), (6, 'Associated Computing, Inc');

CREATE TABLE distributors_upd (did INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dname VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO distributors_upd
VALUES (5, 'Gizmo Transglobal*');
```

Is there an effective query to get the result of a `UPSERT` without actually changing the target table `distributors`?

I tried to mimic the effect with:

```
WITH distributors_updated AS (
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname)
    (TABLE distributors_upd)
    ON CONFLICT (did) DO UPDATE SET dname = EXCLUDED.dname
    RETURNING *
)
--SELECT * FROM distributors;
SELECT * FROM distributors_updated;
```

Neither one of the last two lines gives the would-be result:

```
 did |           dname           
-----+---------------------------
   6 | Associated Computing, Inc
   5 | Gizmo Transglobal*
```

The first `... SELECT * FROM distributors` shows the original table (by design).

```
-----+---------------------------
   5 | Gizmo Transglobal
   6 | Associated Computing, Inc
(2 rows)
```

The second `... SELECT * FROM distributors_updated` shows the change rows only.

```
-----+--------------------
   5 | Gizmo Transglobal*
(1 row)
```

The content of `distributors` is changed either way. Is there an effective query returning the "merged"/"unioned" without actually changing the target `distributors`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ If possible, I'd like to have all rows of `distributors` *after the UPSERT*  **returned** as a relation (instead of written into the DB). In fact, I'd like to avoid writing to the DB as it is kinda SQL-with-temporary-tables style and hard to use with CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the results of the "UPSERT" without actually performing it, you can run a query with `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    did,
    COALESCE(s.dname, t.dname) AS dname   -- in case of conflict, 
                                          -- give precedence to source table
FROM 
    distributors AS t
    FULL JOIN distributors_upd AS s
    USING (did) ;
```

Test at **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=be1499634790fc2daba24efc2fa90bbd)** (thnx to [McNets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/110455/mcnets) for setting it up)

The columns that would be updated on the conflict by the merge will have the source column first in the `COALESCE()` function and the target column second. If the update is more complex, you'll have to use a more complex `COALESCE()` or `CASE` expression. Example:

```
ON CONFLICT UPDATE 
    SET counter = counter + EXCLUDED.counter
```

will become

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t.counter + s.counter, t.counter, s.counter) AS counter
```